# how to access specific item in nested list from telethon GetContactsRequest with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested-lists, telethon

i have an output from telethon GetContactsRequest, like this (to be shorted, i limited contacts to 2):

```
Contacts(contacts=[Contact(user_id=123456789, mutual=True), Contact(user_id=987654321, mutual=True)],
         users=[User(id=123456789, contact=True, etc=123), User(id=987654321, contact=True, etc=123)]
         )
```

in my head i have 2 named lists inside a list (i'm new to telethon and python and its hard to explain more)
in my code i want to access `user_id`s inside `contacts` (not `users`) which i bolded them
or better: i want to append them to a list to finally have something like:

```
contacts_user_id = [123456789, 987654321]
```

please help if there is any soloution, i can't find out anything and i dont know this type of lists.

Comment: Does this FAQ entry solve your issue? https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/faq.html#how-do-i-access-a-field

Comment: oh how could you find it, ill try it and write here if it works, thanks